# ORM for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, orm

Did anyone managed to implement any ORM for Wordpress? I have tried wp-orm (https://github.com/brandonwamboldt/wp-orm) but if I try to use

```
require 'wp-orm/wp-orm.php';

use WordPress\Orm\Model\User;
```

inside my plugin, I got error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in /xxxxx on line

where us **use**.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you...

Comment: Your version of php isn't 5.3 or greater.

Comment: Hi...no...Current PHP version: 5.4.24

Answer (score 2):

Ok...I figure it out, if you are creating a plugin, you have to use USE outside your functions....